# Command equivalent to Keyboard enter press in shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting

i have 3-4 read command in sequence and i have to press enter after the execution of every read command. I want to automate that press keyboard enter key after a read command is executed in my shell script.

Comment: Include the shell you are using - `<shell>` is POSIX shell and very limited compared to later shells like bash.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that?

```
yes | your_script.sh
```

Comment: Got it worked, The read commands were in a shell script and i wanted to parametrise the read, after the parameters are passed through command line, the read was not terminated, so i added another event as a timer for 5 seconds and then added a blank echo to get the next read in next line.